# Javascript format number of decimal places in float

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anybody help me with this issue i'm having? I'm using the following code to get the value of an input field

```
parseFloat($("#salaryFrom").val());
```

The only problem is that if the value in the salaryFrom field ends with a 0 it's getting cut of from the results. e.g. The value 8.50 is being returned as 8.5 and I need it to return 8.50

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Comment: That's what happens when you convert a string to a number, leading and following zeros are removed

Comment: if you want 8.50 it mean you want keep the value as a string. 8.5 or 8.50 are just string representation of the same float.

Comment: On a sidenote: You could always look into numeric frameworks, ie those that handle currency, decimals, percents, etc, such as `autonumeric.js`: http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a float 8.50 an 8.5 are identical. However when you convert your number to a string you can specify the number of decimal places you would like to use with the function toFixed() e.g.

```
var a = parseFloat($("#salaryFrom").val());
var b = a.toFixed(2);
```

The function toFixed() takes the number of decimal places you would like to format your number to, in this case 2.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has a toFixed() function to format floats. So do try that.

```
 tmp = parseFloat($("#salaryFrom").val());
 formatted_val = tmp.toFixed(2);
 alert(formatted_val);
```

Comment: So why use parseFloat to get a number, only to use toFixed to convert it back to a string ?

Comment: @adeneo Because String.prototype.fixed() does something different

Comment: @Jonathan - Yes, but what exactly? `parseFloat("8.50").toFixed(2) === "8.50";` <- what's the point

Comment: `parseFloat("008.5000").toFixed(2) === "8.50";`

Comment: Perhaps the poster plans to do some calculation with the number after they called parseFloat and then wanted to display the result to the user in a particular format.

Comment: @Jonathan - that's true, but the OP is saying the value is `"8.50"`, and after parsing it as a number, it's `8.5`, and the answers says the OP should convert it back to a string and get `"8.50"`, but why ? Either you have a number, wich will always be `8.5`, or you just stick with the string !

Answer (score 0):

Use `.toFixed(2)` in javascript. (2) - its optional The number of digits after the decimal point. Default is 0 (no digits after the decimal point)

```
var num = 8.5;
console.log(num.toFixed(2))
```

Example: Using toFixed

```
var numObj = 12345.6789;

numObj.toFixed();       // Returns '12346': note rounding, no fractional part
numObj.toFixed(1);      // Returns '12345.7': note rounding
numObj.toFixed(6);      // Returns '12345.678900': note added zeros
(1.23e+20).toFixed(2);  // Returns '123000000000000000000.00'
(1.23e-10).toFixed(2);  // Returns '0.00'
2.34.toFixed(1);        // Returns '2.3'
-2.34.toFixed(1);       // Returns -2.3 (due to operator precedence, negative number literals don't return a string...)
(-2.34).toFixed(1);     // Returns '-2.3' (...unless you use parentheses)
```